# xml not being validated without namespace prefix

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have an xml that I wanted to verify against an xsd (with multiple schemas). The xml is as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Interchange xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.abc.com.au/eApplications/Interchange/4.2">
  <InterchangeID>19768</InterchangeID>......</Interchange>
```

This xml didn't pass the validation and was giving me the following error:

```
The 'http://www.abc.com.au/eApplications/Interchange/4.2:Interchange' element is not declared.
```

When I introduced namespace with xml like this:

```
xmlns:ns="http://www.abc.com.au/eApplications/Interchange/4.2"
```

The error was gone, even I didn't introduce namespace prefix like  or  with any of the xml tags like:

```
<ns:Interchange>
   <ns:InterchangeID>...
```

**My Findings:**
The xml passes the validation if I either introduce **:ns** as a namespace or remove the line completely (after the parent Interchange tag) containing all the namespace references defined and keep it like that:

```
<Interchange>
  <InterchangeId>....
```

which is obviously not good.

Though I was able to fix this by the method explained above, I want to know the reason behind this as I couldn't find it after going through many links [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181888/what-does-xmlns-in-xml-mean), [A Ten-Minute Guide to XML Namespaces](http://books.xmlschemata.org/relaxng/relax-CHP-11-SECT-1.html) and [XML Namespaces Explained](https://www.sitepoint.com/xml-namespaces-explained/)

**Edit**
I'm attaching the xsd here:

```
enter code here
<xs:schema xmlns:eapp="http://www.abc.com.au/eApps/iChange/4.2"
     elementFormDefault="qualified"
      targetNamespace="http://www.abc.com.au/eApps/iChange/4.2"
      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

      <xs:include schemaLocation="abc_datatypes.xsd"/>
      <xs:complexType name="abcType">
       <xs:sequence> </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    </xs:schema>

  and the xml sample that passes validation is something like:


<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="url"
    xmlns:orig="url/OServices" xmlns:ns="http://url/eApps/IChange/4.2">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <or:Originate>
       <!--Optional:-->
       <or:data>
       <ns:InID>2229</ns:InID>
       <ns:ReceiverID>CFS</ns:ReceiverID>
    </or:data>
   </or:Originate>
   </soapenv:Body>
 </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: what is the XSD definition for the `Interchange` element?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: When you remove the namespace prefix the root node simply becomes a completely unknown node -- and an unknown node is treated as a warning, not an error.  See [XDocument.Validate is always successful](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17232575/3744182).  In general any globally defined element can be a root element, see [XML Schema: root element](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8854144/3744182), which may be why this is a warning not an error.

Comment: It's coming as an error, not warning

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

> **My Findings:** The xml passes the validation if I either introduce :ns as a namespace or remove the line completely (after the parent
>   Interchange tag) containing all the namespace references defined and
>   keep it like that:
>
> ```
> <Interchange>
>   <InterchangeId>....
> ```
>
> which is obviously not good.

It passes validation because both methods remove the default namespace.

## Additional explanation...

> This xml didn't pass the validation and was giving me the following
>   error:
>
> ```
> The 'http://www.abc.com.au/eApplications/Interchange/4.2:Interchange' element is not declared.
> ```

You didn't supply the schema so we can't verify, but what this is saying is that the `Interchange` element in the `` namespace does not exist in the schema.

When you declare a namespace without a prefix (`xmlns="some uri"`) that becomes the default namespace for that context.

Since you say there aren't any validation errors when you remove `xmlns="http://www.abc.com.au/eApplications/Interchange/4.2"` completely, this leads me to believe that `Interchange` is not in a namespace in the schema.

> When I introduced namespace with xml like this:
>
> ```
> xmlns:ns="http://www.abc.com.au/eApplications/Interchange/4.2"
> ```
>
> The error was gone,...

That's because you bound the namespace uri `http://www.abc.com.au/eApplications/Interchange/4.2` to the prefix `ns` and now there is not a default namespace.

Comment: I'm sure I have the right xml built-up, but probably I'm confusing by passing the wrong startup tag (like 'Interchange') as this was generated automatically by using the .cs provided with xsd.